# How to add properties to Ember model that you don't want to persist into database?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model, which has some properties that I obviously want to fetch from database. In addition to this I want to add a "checked" property to that model, which determines, if the actual model element is checked on the user interface. (for example a model record represents an email, and the checked property determines if it is selected for deletion) And obviously I don't want to persist it to the database, I would like to set a default value to this, and than change it via ui actions).

My guess is that these kind of information should be stored at the controller level, but it is an ArrayController, so a single property in the controller won't do.

I'm sure it's not too difficult to solve, but I'm a newbie, and I could not find the answer in the ember guide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about using a controller. ArrayControllers have itemControllers. You want to specify an item controller and then put the checked attribute there. For example:

```
App.MailController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'email'
});

App.EmailController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  checked: false
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this applies to ember 2.8/2.9+   Any ideas on a solution for a newer version of ember?